# How to list elements of an object in React Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to list the elements of the objects in my Typescript react project.
If I make in this way:

```
const data = Dependencies.backend.getList(caseDetailUrl + this.props.id);
data.then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
```

The output is but when I refresh page it prints 2 times I don't know why:

```
{
    "id": "669f83",
    "creation_date": "2022-01-13 10:33:06.046652+01:00",
    "case_type": "Sum",
    "current_stage": "",
    "last_change_date": "2022-01-14 14:35:17.563449+01:00",
    "status": 1,
}
```

I want to display these info but I can't.

Firstly, I try:

```
let case_value
data.then(res => {
      case_value.push(res)
    })
```

and It shows an error:

*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')*

And when I use .map instead of .then

*Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<unknown[] | undefined>'.ts(2339)*

**Updated code**

```
   const data = Dependencies.backend.getList(caseDetailUrl + this.props.id);
    type resultType = Record<number, string>
    let case_value : Array<resultType>
    data.then(res => {
      case_value.push(res)
    })
```

My whole code is:

```
import React from "react";
import { Dependencies } from "../../../shared/utils/dependencies";
import { caseDetailUrl } from "../../constants/backend-constants";

interface CaseDetailProps {
  id: string,
}

class CaseDetail extends React.Component<CaseDetailProps> {

  render() {
    const data = Dependencies.backend.getList(caseDetailUrl + this.props.id);
    let case_value
    data.then(res => {
      case_value.push(res)
    })
    return (
      <div className="caseDetail">
        <h1>Hi!</h1>
        <h3>{this.props.id}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CaseDetail;
```

How can I display it?

Answer (score 0):

The error is certain as the type for `case_value` variable is not defined. Hence, you cannot read properties of `undefined` variable.

```
 let case_value  //here the case_value is just declared with no type. 
    data.then(res => {
      case_value.push(res)
    })
```

How can compiler know that there is a method called `push` available on it. Therfore, first define the type of it and then use its available properties/methods.

```
 let case_value : Array<provide-type-of-res-here>
    data.then(res => {
      case_value.push(res)
    })
```

For ex: if `res` looks like this.

```
res = {
1 : "hello"
2 : "thanks"
}
```

its type can be like :

```
type resultType = {
1 : string,
2 : string,
}
```

or

```
type resultType = Record<number, string>
```

and then pass this type to Array<{here}>

```
 let case_value : Array<resultType>
    data.then(res => {
      case_value.push(res)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Now I'm getting an another error:

```Argument of type 'unknown[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<number, string>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Record<number, string>'.````

I'll add updated code

Comment: As I mentioned, you have to write the type of "res" . Because, I don't know how your variable "res" looks like. Right? so, I have just showed you an example in my answer. You create the type and pass it to Array<here>. That makes sense. Please let me know if there is any problem.